# System(command) returns false on production server: Ruby on Rails

Tags: linux, shell, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using [system()](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands) to call Linux shell command from rails-controller. 
 I am using [Audible magic API](http://audiblemagic.com/technology.php) to generate fingerprints of audio file.

**Sample Code:**

```
system ("/usr/local/lib/media2xml -c AppOwner -a AppName -i temp_inputFile.mp3 -A  > temp_response.xml")
```

**Explanation**

*command runs Linux executable file with some params and inputFile and create response fingerprints on temp_response.xml*

If I type this command on terminal there is no error and every thing work fine. 
But When I use it from my rails controller then **system(#{command}) returns false** with [exit code](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/exitcodes.html) **127**

Web server is **Thin**. 
Rails 3.2

Need Help, 
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today.But my command is 'python xxxx'.It's cause by system environment.Maybe some lib dependency of this command is missing or not to be set in default PATH.You shoud check the 'media2xml' script.If the script is #/usr/bin/xxx,then make sure the /usr/bin/xxx is in correct version to the Rails App.